# Commands in Script

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have a question on creating commands in Powershell.

I was able to successfully execute the following command which I found [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/replace-a-word-in-multiple-text-files-windows-10/):

```
Get-ChildItem 'Path-to-files\*.txt' -Recurse | ForEach {
(Get-Content $_ | ForEach { $_ -replace 'Original-Word', 'New-Word' }) |
Set-Content $_
}
```

It worked great, but I want to not only find a string and replace it, I also want to find a string and remove that line as well as a few lines below it.
The thing is, I don't know what command string to use.
I have been searching around but can't seem to find what I am looking for. I found the documentation on the [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6), and [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6), but I don't find the -replace syntax that can lead to my finding what to use to remove lines.
I also need to be able to count characters in the line.

Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: `-replace` uses regular expressions. I recommend you find some good references on regular expressions and how to use them.

Comment: Learn about [RegEx](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) and test your RE online at [Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/),[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) but be prepared you may have to `Get-Content -raw` and use multiline RegExes with a prefix like `(?sm)` to properly define your replacements.

Comment: Plus, to count the character on a line stored in `$_`, simply use `$_.Length`. These tips should get you started, but your question is too broad in its current form.

Comment: Thanks. You helped. Regular Expressions is what I am looking for. I will do some digging into these. Thanks all.